# android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork error while android app makes http api

Tags: android, api, rest, http, android-network-security-config

I've developed an android app. The app works fine while app makes the HTTP API calls with **https://**. But app throws the error when app makes the same HTTP API calls with **http://**.

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
```

there are no issues with APIs. I've tested the APIs (both **https** and **http**) with the postman.

I'm using Volley library and OkHttp library for HTTP API calls.

kindly help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Android P or above devices?

Comment: No. I'm using android 8.